# Codeigniter Image upload issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter upload library to upload multiple images. Mostly it is working fine, but in some cases the image is not uploading.

**Function:**

```
    function do_upload_img()
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['portfolioimg']['size']) != 0){
           $name_array = array();
           $files = $_FILES;
           $cpt = count($_FILES['portfolioimg']['name']);

           // $config['source_image'] = ''; //get original image
           $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
           $config['wm_overlay_path'] = './assets/img/watermark.png';
           $config['quality'] = 50;
           $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
           $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
           $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

           for($i=0; $i<=$cpt-1; $i++)
           {
               $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['portfolioimg']['name'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['portfolioimg']['type'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['portfolioimg']['tmp_name'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['portfolioimg']['error'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['portfolioimg']['size'][$i];    

               $imgnam = rand(10,1000000).time();
               $ext = pathinfo($files['portfolioimg']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
               if($this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($imgnam))){
                      $data = $this->upload->do_upload();
                      $config['source_image'] = './assets/portfolio_img/' . 'Rookie_'.$imgnam.'.'.$ext;
                      $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                      $this->image_lib->watermark(); 
                      $name_array[] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                      $this->create_thumbnail('./assets/portfolio_img/',$imgnam,$ext);
               }else{
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('falsemsg','Only jpg, jpeg, png files are allowed to be uploaded.');
               }
           } 
           return $name_array;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
    private function set_upload_options($imgnam)
    {   
            //upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path']   = './assets/portfolio_img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png|JPEG|JPG|PNG';
        $config['max_size']      = '0';
        $config['overwrite']     = true;
        $config['file_name']     = 'Rookie_'.$imgnam;

        return $config;
    }
```

This is the function that Im using to upload the images. I don't have any idea why it is not working sometimes. So please help me to figure out the error in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $b='portfolioimg';
    $fileName = $_FILES[$b]['name'];
                $images = $fileName;
                $cpt = count($files);
                for($i=1; $i<=$cpt; $i++)
                {
                    $_FILES[$b]['name']= $files[$b]['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES[$b]['type']= $files[$b]['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES[$b]['tmp_name']= $files[$b]['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES[$b]['error']= $files[$b]['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES[$b]['size']= $files[$b]['size'][$i];
                    $uploadPath =  './assets/portfolio_img/';
                    $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|ico';
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload($b.$i)){
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            $im[$i]=$uploadData[$i]['file_name'];
            }
            } 
        $tblValues = array(

        'image'=>$images, // change field name,


    );
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $tblValues);
```

Comment: what make you confuse? Actually the above code also working most of the case but sometime it fails. I want to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $config['upload_path']="./uploads/";
            $config['allowed_types']='jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                echo "file upload success";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "file upload failed";
            }
        }
```

**View:**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>controller/function" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Select File To Upload:<br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile"  />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please mind adding some explanation so that its easier to apprehend than reading a code and performing diff in our minds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you are too late to post it. Good luck (Y) :)